# Pass dynamic id value jquery div jump to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck at jquery div jump to problem. The problem is that i am creating dynamic `<a href="" id="1_1"></a>` and dynamic div also say `<div id="1_1_div"></div>` i am using following jquery function to scroll to a particular div

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#click").click(function (){
                alert ("test");
                //$(this).animate(function(){
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                //});
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My question is how to pass dynamic id to `$("")` Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: String Concatenation: `$("#" + this.id + "_div").offset().top`

Comment: That i got it but the problem is how to call function when we have many `<a href="#" id="1_1">Div1</a> <a href="#" id="1_2">Div2</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $(".click").click(function (){
            alert ("test");
            var divID = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_div';
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(divID).offset().top
                }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

And add `<a class="click" ...`

Comment: Please go through my problem in above comment. i want to pass dynamic ids of `<a></a>` to `#click` so that on click it will scroll to that div

Answer (score 3):

## [Visualize it here](http://jsfiddle.net/8wpr3/)

First, since you have multiple links, use a class to group them:

### HTML

```
<a href="#" id="1_1" class="click">Click me 1_1</a>
<a href="#" id="1_2" class="click">Click me 1_2</a>    
<a href="#" id="1_3" class="click">Click me 1_3</a>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.click', function (e) {
    var theID = $(this).attr('id');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + theID + '_div').offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

I did this with the slight assumption you were dynamically creating these links (hence the delegation).  If they are static and won't change during page load, you can use `$('.click').click(function()...` instead of `$(document).on('click', '.click', function()...`

Comment: Thank you for visualization +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

String Concatenation:

```
$("#" + this.id + "_div").offset().top
```

Note that there is no need to create unique IDs, DOM duo to having tree-like structure provides many different methods for traversing and selecting the target elements.

Since you are generating the elements dynamically you should also delegate the events, you can add classes to your elements and use the `on` method:

```
$('#aStaticParentElement').on('click', '.anchors', function() {
   // TODO:
   // select the target element either by traversing 
   // or by using an identifier
});
```

Answer (score 0):

User this line

```
$("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_div").offset().top
```

...