# Getting TypeError on Animate ScrollTo

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I'm getting a TypeError and can't figure out why.

**jQuery:**

```
    var text_to_insert = '';
    for (var i=0; i<tunnelObject.length; i++) {
        var target = tunnelObject[i].t.name;
        text_to_insert += '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="special_anchor" id="' + target + '">' + target + '</a>';
    }

    $('#list').append(text_to_insert);

    $('#list').on('click', 'a.special_anchor', function() {
        var id = this.id;
        console.log(id);

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
        }, 1200);
    })
```

**HTML:**

```
    <td class="value_width_long" id="tunnels_listing"><span id="list"/></td>
```

If i change the `$(id).offset().top` to say `$('#myDiv').offset().top` it will scroll there just fine. But with the `id`, it's raising this on the console:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '$(id).offset().top')

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

The HTML that should be scrolled to, looks like this:

```
    <!-- Tunnels Section -->
     <div class="tunnels" id="tunnels">
         <!-- Tunnel Header -->
         <div class="div_tunnel_header" id="div_tunnel_header">
            <p class="main_subject first_subject">$_('BOVPN Tunnel')</p>
            <p class="scroll_top btn-link">$_('Top')</p>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" id="tunnel_header_table">
                <tr>
                    <th class="label_width_long">$_('Name')</th>
                    <td class="tnl_name value_width_long"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label_width_long">$_('Gateway Name')</th>
                    <td class="gateway_name value_width_long"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
         ...
```

Because this section can be cloned up x amount of times. The `id="div_tunnel_header"` is changed via jQuery to a unique `id` that matches the `id` from the anchor link from `text_to_insert`.

**Edit Part 2:**

I have a working copy on jsFiddle. On jsFiddle, it works, on my localhost, it doesn't work. But I still get this error:

```
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$(this.id).offset().top')
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/988/

**Edit Part 3:**

Edit part 2 works when array is being used, copied and pasted to my localhost. This edit updates the jsFiddle to use objects instead of an array. It no longer scrolls. Will get same `TypeError` as Edit part 2.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/989/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please replace this line:

```
var id = this.id;
```

with this line:

```
var element = $(this);
```

and instead using 'id' variable, use element - such as:

```
$(id).offset().top // error - id is not a valid selector without # directive
element.offset().top
```

Comment: Thanks, with this it takes away the TypeError. But it will only scroll to where that link that I clicked is, and not the actual div with the id.

Comment: a complete html code with both link tag and destination tag would help... an upload to jsFiddle or some equivalent will be a saver

Comment: Sorry I'm not too familiar with using jsFiddle, especially with additional bootstrap and Cheetah code. I don't know how it would behave. I added the HTML that it should be scrolling to. The `id` changes to match the anchor's `id`.

Comment: use this link: **http://jsfiddle.net/ymzrocks/v1zn773p/**  it demonstrate how to affect a div when clicking on a link.. you can implement your scrolling mechnism on that basis

Comment: So in jsFiddle, this would be what I have. But can't get it to scroll to `hello`. http://jsfiddle.net/v1zn773p/1/

Comment: it hard to help without having the complete html in front of me... i don't see the elements you have so my help is limited

Comment: I have a working copy on jsFiddle on Edit 2. It works as intended on jsFiddle, but it doesn't on localhost. Can you take a look and see maybe why I'm getting that same error?

Comment: the jsFiddle works great - in your script, put all the js code from fiddle inside ready event: $(document).ready(function() { /* your code here */ });

Comment: I copy and pasted in it, and it works perfect. But when I change that `arraylist` from being hardcoded to the objects that I need, it would throw that `TypeError` exception. Tried throwing those object value into an array, and it would still throw same exception. Any thoughts?

Comment: Edit part 3 has the updated jsFiddle that uses the objects instead of an array. It no longer works when that happens. This is the case for my code where I need to use the object values. Can you take a look please.

Comment: It seems like the HTML is hard coded with `first` `second` and so on. It cannot be hard coded since the div are cloned for multiple tunnels, and then values being replaced. The array of objects is an example of what the server side code is. That's why there is the line for changing attributes `id` to the specific `arraylist[i].value`. Any work around for that?

Comment: Found out the problem. The last example would work if there were no escaped characters in the id. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510092/pass-dynamic-id-value-jquery-div-jump-to-function